# Puppet User ID value and Package

Tags: puppet

I am trying to do the following using Puppet on an Ubuntu 10.04:

1. Copy a file that I have to a specific directory which will be owned by a specific user / group that does not exists yet since the package has not been installed
2. Install the package where it will not remove the directory and file that I created

To accomplish item #1, I basically tell Puppet to create a user and group first before copying the file. But the problem is that if I do not give a specific uid for Puppet, it will randomly pick a number like a number for user and not a number for system package.

So, how do I tell Puppet to choose a uid anything more than 1000?

If this is not possible, how do I tell Puppet not to start the package when it installs it. So I would just let Puppet install the package, but do not start the service, then copy my file, then I will start the service.

Answer (score 1):

The user type has a parameter of system => which defaults to false, but can be set to true.  This will generate the user with a UID below 500. Which seems to be what you want.

Ultimately what you'll want to do in my opinion is manage the config directory and the config via puppet as well.

This gives you the ability to do things like such:

```
package { foo: ensure => present }

file {
  fooconfdir: 
    path => '/path/to/fooconfdir',
    ensure => directory,
    user => whatev,
    group => alsowhatev,
    require => Package[foo],
    mode => morewhatev;
  fooconf:
    path => '/path/to/fooconfdir/fooconf',
    ensure => present,
    user => whatev,
    content => template('whatev');
}

service { foo: ensure => running, enable => true, subscribe => File[fooconf] }
```

What that will do , is install your package then manage the config, then restart the service which will use your new config obviously on restart.